# What is the advantage to use kendo.data.Model with dataSource in Kendo UI?

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm new in kendo UI and I don't  fully understand what is the primary goal and advantage of using kendo.data.Model within dataSource.

Comment: It's too bad this was down-voted. This is a valid question. I have never used a data model as part of a data source. And I'm wondering why I should.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if I understand your question. But the datasource is a good way to abstract your interaction with for example twitter:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: {
        // the remote service url
        url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json",

        // JSONP is required for cross-domain AJAX
        dataType: "jsonp",

        // additional parameters sent to the remote service
        data: {
            q: "html5"
        }
    }
},
// describe the result format
schema: {
    // the data which the data source will be bound to is in the "results" field
    data: "results"
}
});
```